# Communicate between two windows forms in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, properties

I have two forms, one is the main form and the other is an options form. So say for example that the user clicks on my menu on the main form: `Tools -> Options`, this would cause my options form to be shown.

My question is how can I send data from my options form back to my main form? I know I could use properties, but I have a lot of options and this seems like an <strike>tedious</strike> odd thing to do.

So what is the best way?

Comment: @Bob: Are you closing your options Form after setting the options and want the main Form opened with option values?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Form1 triggers Form2 to open. Form2 has overloaded constructor which takes calling form as argument and provides its reference to Form2 members. This solves the communication problem. For example I've exposed Label Property as public in Form1 which is modified in Form2.

With this approach you can do communication in different ways.

//**Your Form1**

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 frm = new Form2(this);
        frm.Show();
    }

    public string LabelText
    {
        get { return Lbl.Text; }
        set { Lbl.Text = value; }
    }
}
```

//**Your Form2**

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private Form1 mainForm = null;
    public Form2(Form callingForm)
    {
        mainForm = callingForm as Form1; 
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.mainForm.LabelText = txtMessage.Text;
    }
}
```

[image]
<sub>(source: [ruchitsurati.net](http://demo.ruchitsurati.net/files/frm1.png))</sub>

[image]
<sub>(source: [ruchitsurati.net](http://demo.ruchitsurati.net/files/frm2.png))</sub>

Comment: Awesome answer! Thats exactly what I'm looking for! Thanks! Also I love that black them on XP (it almost makes me miss XP).

Comment: It's the Zune theme for XP. :)

Comment: This leads to tight coupling of the forms Form1 and Form2, I guess instead one should use custom events for such kind of scenarios.

Comment: Woah years of programming in Winforms (as student tho) yet I never came across this functionality and it's very fun to implement...

Comment: But...  it is still coupling to Form1...  Can i just use a generic Form (private Form mainForm = null;) (mainForm = callingForm as Form;)...    i want it to receive data from any Form at all

Answer (score 18):

In the comments to the accepted answer, Neeraj Gulia writes:

> This leads to tight coupling of the forms Form1 and Form2, I guess instead one should use custom events for such kind of scenarios.

The comment is exactly right. The accepted answer is not bad; for simple programs, and especially for people just learning programming and trying to get basic scenarios to work, it's a very useful example of how a pair of forms can interact.

However, it's true that the coupling that example causes can and should be avoided, and that in the particular example, an event would accomplish the same thing in a general-purpose, decoupled way.

Here's an example, using the accepted answer's code as the baseline:

**Form1.cs:**

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 frm = new Form2();

        frm.Button1Click += (s1, e1) => Lbl.Text = ((Form2)s1).Message;

        frm.Show();
    }
}
```

The above code creates a new instance of `Form2`, and then before showing it, adds an event handler to that form's `Button1Click` event.

Note that the expression `(s1, e1) => Lbl.Text = ((Form2)s1).Message` is converted automatically by the compiler to a method that looks something similar to (but definitely not exactly like) this:

```
private void frm_Message(object s1, EventArgs e1)
{
    Lbl.Text = ((Form2)s1).Message;
}
```

There are actually lots of ways/syntaxes to implement and subscribe the event handler. For example, using an anonymous method as the above, you don't really need to cast the `sender` parameter; instead you can just use the `frm` local variable directly: `(s1, e1) => Lbl.Text = frm.Message`.

Going the other way, you don't need to use an anonymous method. You could in fact just declare a regular method just like the compiler-generated one I show above, and then subscribe that method to the event: `frm.Button1Click += frm_Message;` (where you have of course used the name `frm_Message` for the method, just as in my example above).

Regardless of how you do it, of course you will need for `Form2` to actually implement that `Button1Click` event. That's very simple…

**Form2.cs:**

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public event EventHandler Button1Click;

    public string Message { get { return txtMessage.Text; } }

    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        EventHandler handler = Button1Click;

        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }
}
```

In addition to the event, I've also declared a property `Message` that exposes the `Text` property (and *only* the `Text` property, and only as read-only in fact) of the `txtMessage` control. This allows the subscriber to the event to get the value and do whatever it needs to with it.

Note that all that the event does is to alert the subscriber that the button has in fact been clicked. It's up to the subscriber to decide how to interpret or react to that event (e.g. by retrieving the value of the `Message` property and assigning it to something).

Alternatively, you could in fact deliver the text along with the event itself, by declaring a new `EventArgs` sub-class and using that for the event instead:

```
public class MessageEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public string Message { get; private set; }

    public MessageEventArgs(string message)
    {
        Message = message;
    }
}

public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public event EventHandler<MessageEventArgs> Button1Click;

    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        EventHandler handler = Button1Click;

        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new MessageEventArgs(txtMessage.Text));
        }
    }
}
```

Then the subscriber can just retrieve the message value directly from the event object:

```
frm.Button1Click += (sender, e) => Lbl.Text = e.Message;
```

The important thing note in all of the above variations is that at no point does the class `Form2` need to know anything about `Form1`. Having `Form1` know about `Form2` is unavoidable; after all, that's the object that will create a new `Form2` instance and use it. But the relationship can be asymmetrical, with `Form2` being usable by *any* object that needs the features it offers. By exposing the functionality as an event (and optionally with a property), it makes itself useful without limiting its usefulness to only the `Form1` class.

Answer (score 7):

The best in this case would be to have some `OptionsService` class/interface that is accessible via `IServiceProvider`.

Just add an event when something changes, and the rest of the app can respond to it.

Answer (score 3):

There are lots of ways to perform communication between two Forms. 
Some of them have already been explained to you. I am showing you the other way around.

Assuming you have to update some settings from the child form to the parent form. You can make use of these two ways as well :

1. Using System.Action  (Here you simply pass the main forms function as the parameter to the child form like a callback function)
2. OpenForms Method ( You directly call one of your open forms)

**Using System.Action**

You can think of it as a callback function passed to the child form.

```
// -------- IN THE MAIN FORM --------

// CALLING THE CHILD FORM IN YOUR CODE LOOKS LIKE THIS
Options frmOptions = new Options(UpdateSettings);
frmOptions.Show();

// YOUR FUNCTION IN THE MAIN FORM TO BE EXECUTED
public void UpdateSettings(string data)
{
   // DO YOUR STUFF HERE
}

// -------- IN THE CHILD FORM --------

Action<string> UpdateSettings = null;

// IN THE CHILD FORMS CONSTRUCTOR
public Options(Action<string> UpdateSettings)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.UpdateSettings = UpdateSettings;
}

private void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // CALLING THE CALLBACK FUNCTION
    if (UpdateSettings != null)
        UpdateSettings("some data");
}
```

**OpenForms Method**

This method is easy (**2 lines**). But only works with forms that are open.
All you need to do is add these two lines where ever you want to pass some data.

```
Main frmMain = (Main)Application.OpenForms["Main"];
frmMain.UpdateSettings("Some data");
```

Answer (score 1):

Properties is one option, shared static class - another option, events - another option...

Comment: Arguments to the constructor, method calls, ... :-)

Answer (score 1):

You might try [AutoMapper](http://www.codeplex.com/AutoMapper).  Keep your options in a separate class and then use AutoMapper to shuttle the data between the class and the form.

Answer (score 1):

Create a Class and put all your properties inside the class .. Create a Property in the parent class and set it from your child (options) form

Answer (score 1):

You can have a function in Form B like so:

```
public SettingsResults GetNewSettings()
{
    if(this.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.Ok)
    {
         return new SettingsResult { ... };
    }
    else
    {
         return null;
    }
}
```

And you can call it like this:

```
...
using(var fb = new FormB())
{
    var s = fb.GetNewSettings();
    ...
    // Notify other parts of the application that settings have changed.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

MVC, MVP, MVVM -- slight overkill for someone admittedly saying they want tutorials.  Those are theories that have entire courses dedicated to them.

As already posted, passing an object around is probably easiest.  If treating a class as an object (interchangeable in this sense) is new, then you may want to spend another 2-4 weeks figuring out properties and constructors and such.

I'm not a C# master by any means, but these concepts need to be pretty concrete if you want to go much further beyond passing values between two forms (also classes/objects in their own right).  Not trying to be mean here at all, it just sounds like you're moving from something like VB6 (or any language with globals) to something far more structured.

Eventually, it will click.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to deal with communication between containers is to implement an observer class

The observer pattern is a software design pattern in which an object, called the subject, maintains a list of its dependents, called observers, and notifies them automatically of any state changes, usually by calling one of their methods. 
(Wikipedia)

the way i do this is creating an Observer class, and inside it write something like this:

```
1    public delegate void dlFuncToBeImplemented(string signal);
2    public static event dlFuncToBeImplemented OnFuncToBeImplemented;
3    public static void FuncToBeImplemented(string signal)
4    {
5         OnFuncToBeImplemented(signal);
6    }
```

so basically: the first line says that there would be a function that somebody else will implement

the second line is creating an event that occurs when the delegated function will call

and the third line is the creation of the function that calls the event

so in your UserControl, you should add a function like this:

```
private void ObserverRegister()//will contain all observer function registration
{
    Observer.OnFuncToBeImplemented += Observer_OnFuncToBeImplemented;
    /*and more observer function registration............*/
}


void Observer_OnFuncToBeImplemented(string signal)//the function that will occur when  FuncToBeImplemented(signal) will call 
{
    MessageBox.Show("Signal "+signal+" received!", "Atention!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
}
```

and in your Form you should do something like:

```
public static int signal = 0;

public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      Observer.FuncToBeImplemented(signal);//will call the event in the user control
}
```

and now, you can register this function to a whole bunch of other controls and containers and they will all get the signal

I hope this would help :)

Comment: Great option for those who would like their forms to be uncoupled

Answer (score 0):

This is probably sidestepping your problem a little bit, but my settings dialog uses the Application Settings construct. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k4s6c3a0.aspx

I can't find a good example that's similar to how I do it (which is actually having an actual class+object), but this covers another way of doing it:

[Reading default application settings in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49269/reading-default-application-settings-in-c)

Comment: This is nice, but I'm not interested in storing the settings. I just want these settings to be relayed to the main form.

Answer (score 0):

A form is a class, just like any other class.  Add some public variables to your form class and set them when they click the button to close the form (technically they are just hiding it).

A VB.NET example, but you'll get the idea -

In your OptionsForm class:

```
Public Option1 as String = ""
```

etc. Set them when they hit the "Ok" button.

So in your main form, when they hit the "options" button - you create your options form:

```
OptionsForm.ShowDialog()
```

when it exits, you harvest your option settings from the public variables on the form:

```
option1 = OptionsForm.Option1
```

etc.