# How to pass output of a linq query to another form in C#

Tags: linq

I have a Linq query and I want to pass the ouput (userid) to another form for further processing.

```
 var userid = from auser in allusers.Users where auser.Username == nameString
        select new { id = auser.UserId };
```

so only `UserId` is stored in variable `userid` and I want to use this value in another form.
Is there any way we can do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to return the result of a query you cannot use anonymous types. You must create a concrete class. In your specific case you could just use an `int?` like this:

```
int? userid = (from auser in allusers.Users
               where auser.Username == nameString
               select auser.UserId).SingleOrDefault();
```

Comment: @Mark Thanks.can you also refer me to some website or some code which I can refer to since I am new to this.. 
what I was trying is to give the output of this var..to some varibale, but i guess we cannot do that coz there's no way we can convert it to appropiate type...it it true

Comment: now how can I pass this value in userid to another form sir.
Thanks for helping me out.

Comment: @Ani: If you only want to pass a single value rather than a query, use Single to get the value and pass that value using the same technique as you would to pass any other value between forms, e.g. see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1665533/communicate-between-two-windows-forms-in-c - See my updated code.

Answer (score 0):

```
    IEnumerable <TableName> result = from x in dataBase.TableName
                                     select x;     
    methodName(result);



    private void methodName (IEnumerable<TableName> result) 
    {
     codes.....
    }
```