# How to transfer selected data into main form?

Tags: .net, data-structures

Suppose you have a registration form with textboxes to hold a StudentId and a CourseId.
Also provided is a button which opens a second form which allows you to lookup a StudentId using by their first or last name.

How return the StudentId from the search form, and load it into the StudentId textbox on the registration form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1665533/communicate-between-two-windows-forms-in-c/1665688#1665688) answer explains the solution nicely.

Basically, you create a new constructor for your search form which takes a form object as a parameter. When you create call your search form, you pass a reference to the registration form with it.

When the search form finds the studentId, it uses this reference to the registration form to call a public method in the registration form which populates the studentId textbox.