# How can I remove communication delay between 2 forms?

Tags: c#, winforms

currently i am using a handmade Messagebox build by the idea of:

[Communicate between two windows forms in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1665533/communicate-between-two-windows-forms-in-c-sharp)

this solution put as base of a section of my project i found out it is not reacting straight away when i use this code:

```
//Form 1
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Framerate = "Test1";
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 frm = new Form2(this);
        frm.Show();

        label2.Text = Framerate; // this statement is delayed / working too soon
    }

    public string Framerate
    {
        get { return label1.Text; }
        set { label1.Text = value; }
    }
}
```

in Form2 i am changing Framerate. 
when debugging this project i found out FrameRate is changing in Form2 and also on Form1 but when i run it further

```
  label2.Text = Framerate
```

is not changed. my question, why is it not changing right away, and what can i do to get it to change right away

edit:

it seems it runs whole button1_click before showing Form2.

Label1.Text is changed when i' m closing Form2 (bacause of the get / set stuff) but that is too late for my application

EDIT:

after some messing arround i found an answer myself, maybe not nice but working for my application:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Framerate = "Test1";
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 frm = new Form2(this);
        frm.Show();
    }
    private void test()
    {
        label2.Text = Framerate;
    }

    public string Framerate
    {
        get { return label1.Text; }
        set
        {
            label1.Text = value;
            test();
        }
    }
}
```

everyone thanks for trying to help me.

Comment: LarsTech, i cant answer my own question within 7 hours

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after some messing arround i found an answer myself, maybe not nice but working for my application:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Framerate = "Test1";
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 frm = new Form2(this);
        frm.Show();
    }
    private void test()
    {
        label2.Text = Framerate;
    }

    public string Framerate
    {
        get { return label1.Text; }
        set
        {
            label1.Text = value;
            test();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try a `label2.Refresh();` after `label2.Text = Framerate;`.

Comment: Then try a `Thread.Sleep(10);` after `frm.Show();` in the button-click event.

Answer (score 1):

You need to either include a reference to Form1.Label2 in your Form2, or have Form2 raise an event that Form1 is listening to for the Framerate change.