# Start timer from another form

Tags: c#, winforms, events, stopwatch

In my project I have two forms `mainForm` and `testingForm`.
In `mainForm` i have `button1`, and in `testingForm`, I have:

```
Stopwatch measure = new Stopwatch();
```

When the user clicks `button1`, i want the `measure` stopwatch to start, and to make other events with it. How can I do that? I researched a lot, but nothing helped...

Comment: is there any specific reason for not having the stopwatch on main form

Comment: yes, it is. but if this doesn't help you, I don't want to write more details, because it is just a little application that helps me to measure some data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the Stopwatch a property of testingform.  When the button is clicked you create the new Stopwatch in mainform and then assign it to the testingform property

Code for testingform

```
 private Stopwatch _Measure;
        public Stopwatch Measure
        {
            get
            {
                return _Measure;
            } 
            set 
            { _Measure = value;
                // Do some stuff
            }
        }
```

Code for mainform

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Stopwatch measure = new Stopwatch();
            testingform.Measure = measure;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can bring the timer into a scope where both `mainForm` and `testingForm` can use it, maybe at the application level.

Comment: this would be helpful I think, but could you give me more indications?

Comment: Instead of making your timer a member of one of the forms, make it a member of the application class, or some class in which both forms can access and use the timer.

Answer (score 1):

In testingForm

```
Stopwatch measure = new Stopwatch();

public Stopwatch Watch { get { return measure; } }
```

In mainForm

```
testingForm frm = new testingForm();
frm.Watch.Start();
//...
frm.Watch.Stop();
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your're wanting the Main Form to contain and control all aspects of the program (the stopwatch, or anything for that matter), you can follow [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1665533/communicate-between-two-windows-forms-in-c-sharp).

The only thing you'll need to change is making the stopwatch a property of the MainForm and having Form2 call the action by reference.