# Forms Communication

Tags: c#, winforms, communication

I have 2 forms which consist of:

**Form1:**

2buttons named:
btnCopy and
btnPaste
(with functions inside like rtb.Copy(); and rtb.Paste(); that should work for richtextbox in Form2)

**Form2:**

1richtextbox named: rtb

**My question was:**
How can I communicate between the 2buttons from Form1 (with its functions) and the richtextbox in Form2.

like: When I type text inside richtextbox(rtb) in Form2 then i SelectAll text then I Press the CopyButton(btnCopy) from Form1, text should be copied same as when I Press PasteButton(btnPaste) from Form1, text that has been copied should be Paste in RichTextBox(rtb) that could be Found on Form2 .

How can I do that?

Comment: Any reason, why do you need 2 Forms, you could have the richtextbox in the same form..If you still need to use 2 Forms, is the second for a Modal ?

Comment: form1 served as container, im doing IDE btw ... @jacobaloysious

Comment: Does Form1 calls Form2 first? or other way around? or some other forms calls Form1 and Form2 (which i doubt)?

Comment: @Edper, can have another button in Form1 named btnNew, then Form2 will be called then method will continue ...

Comment: @Elegiac You  mean Form1 is MDI parent and Form2 is inside the MDI?

Comment: @Edper yep ... btw i already try this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1665533/communicate-between-two-windows-forms-in-c-sharp but i got problem regarding the "this"

Comment: also its a void method i guess for .Copy and .Paste so it couldnt be a string ...

Comment: why votedown? o.0 .........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you have `Form1` and `ToolStrip Button` name `PasteToolStripButton` like:

```
  public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Form2 formChild;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Load += new EventHandler(Form1_Load);
    }

    void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       formChild = new Form2();
       formChild.MdiParent = this;
       formChild.Show();            
    }


   private void CopyToolStripButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        formChild.CopyText(); // Method to copy Rich Text Box in Form2
    }

    private void PasteToolStripButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        formChild.PasteText(); // Method in Form2 to Paste to the RichTextBox in Form2
    }
```

}

In your `Form2` you need to add a `Public` method named `PasteText` and `CopyText` like:

```
  public void PasteText()
  {
     rtbChild.Text = Clipboard.GetText(); // this one simulates the rtb.Paste()
  }

  public void CopyText()
  {
     rtb.Copy(); 
  }
```

I also named the `RichTextBox` in `Form2` as `rtbChild` so every time you click for example paste in will be copied in your `RichTextBox` in `Form2`.

Comment: wheres the rtb.Copy code and rtb.Paste execution in here sir?

Comment: error in form1 the name 'rtb' does not exit in the current context ... the rtb must be in form2 sir ... @Edper

Comment: change rtb to the name of your RichTextBox let's say if the name is RichTextBox1 then it should be RichTextBox1.

Comment: the rtb must be in form2 sir ... 2buttons only on form1 and form2 with a richtextbox

Comment: i also i try to commend the "rtb.Copy();" but another error appears pointing the content inside Form1_Load : Form that was specified to be the MdiParent for this form is not an MdiCOntainer.

Comment: You need to make your Form1 property IsMdiContaier to True. I added on the Form2 to Copy text from rtb in form2. check my update.

Comment: i commented this line: //formChild.MdiParent = this; and it worked coz it brought an error ... you can test that error if you want sir

Comment: sir can we fix the error for formChild.MdiParent = this? @Edper

Comment: I add the the formChild.MdiParent = this; so that Form2 will be inside the Mdi parent Form1. If you don't want then you could remove that.

Answer (score 0):

Create a public property on Form1 then set it from Form2.
EDIT:
On Form1:
public string TextForRTB {get; set;}

On Form2:
Form1 a = new  Form1();
a.TextForRtb = rtb.Text;

Answer (score 0):

Sol1: Pass one of the forms to the other, as `Form1(Form parent){....}` in the constructor, then you should see it's public properties and methods.

Sol2: Create custom events to raise it when text changed on your rich text box, so than the forms that initialized the form with this rich box will do something, like enable/disable a button or something

...Actually, there is a lot of solutions to this kind of behavior, and I wonder why you need to put your text box in a different form from your buttons that seems to be related very closely in business logic together!

Answer (score 0):

You could expose 2 methods `GetRichTextBoxContent` and `SetRichTextBoxContent` in `Form2`. 
Which would update the contents of `richTextBox` in `Form2`.

Then you could work on the `Instance` of `Form2` form `Form1`

**Note:** The major think here is how you get the `Instance` of `Form2`. It is up to your implementation to get that instance.

```
public class Form2 : Form
{
    public string GetRichTextBoxContent()
    {
        return this.richTextBox1.Text;
    }

    public void SetRichTextBoxContent(string content)
    {
        this.richTextBox1.Text = content;
    } 
}

public class Form1 : Form
{
    //Based on your implementation 
    Form2 form2 = new Form2();

    private void Button_CopyClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var contentFromRtb = form2.GetRichTextBoxContent();
    } 
    private void Button_PasteClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var someContent = "Content to be copied to text box"
        form2.SetRichTextBoxContent(someContent );
    } 
}
```

Comment: wheres the rtb.Copy code and rtb.Paste execution in here sir?

Comment: btw, you dont need `copy` or `Paste` as `this.richTextBox1.Text` would get and set the contents for you..

Comment: it doesnt work sir ... everytime i select text from rtb then press the button_copy from form1 and button_paste then i select in rtb theres no change sir ... it keeps its focus on buttons .what should i do?