# Communication between two classes via form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, class

I am using a Windows Form `MainForm` which calls the following:

```
FileSystemLayer FSL = new FileSystemLayer();
DatabaseLayer DBL = new DatabaseLayer();
```

**What I want to do:**

(inside the DatabaseLayer class)

```
String SomeString = MainForm.FSL.AnotherString;
```

**The problem**

> The FileSystemLayer FSL is inaccessible due to its protection level

**I've tried**

```
public FileSystemLayer FSL = new FileSystemLayer();
public DatabaseLayer DBL = new DatabaseLayer();
```

But it gave the result

> Inconsistent accessibility: 'DatabaseLayer' is less accessible than
>   field 'MainForm.DBL'

So I'm hoping someone can give me some advice on how to communicate between the two classes.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1665533/communicate-between-two-windows-forms-in-c-sharp

Comment: If you made the DatabaseLayer Class public, I think this would solve the problem. But the bigger issue is that I think you should heed the advice of the link above, or at lease pass a reference to FSL down to DBL instead of trying to access FSL from DBL after the fact. Think public DatabaseLayer DBL = new DatabaseLayer(FileSystemLayer fSL);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying several suggested solutions, that I couldn't manage to apply, I instead changed the hierarchy of the class calling like described below. Thanks to the people taking time to help me towards a solution.

[image]

(Them Paint skillz)

Answer (score 0):

That message is telling you that while the `DBL` member field of the main form is declared as `public` the type itself (`DatabaseLayer`) is declared as something other than `public`, most likely `private`, or `internal`

So you can solve the problem by modifying the the DatabaseLayer class and making it `public class DatabaseLayer`.

That said, the main purpose of encapsulating functionality into the file system layer and the database layer respectively is to loosen coupling. But if you expose one to the other directly and allow one to call into the other than you're sort of throwing the benefit out the window. You should consider alternative approaches to facilitating communication between the two layers.

Comment: When I change the DatabaseLayer class to public all the public functions in the class get the error message instead.

Comment: and when I make the functions private they can not be accessed from my MainForm

Comment: The functions in the class that you are exposing should be marked public. The class itself can be public or internal. If you make the class internal, than make the DBL field internal as well (instead of public).

Comment: Are all of your mentioned classes in the same assembly?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the DatabaseLayer class is defined as internal so if you want to make a property of that type to be accessible publicly, you should define the type (DatabaseLayer) public too, or you may make your property less visible by defining it as internal.

But as also it seems that you are using some kind of layering it wouldn't be the right way to achieve what you are looking for.