# C# how to pass value from form to form through datagridview?

Tags: c#, forms, datagridview

i have form, it goes like this

[image: picture 1]

that `nomor tabungan` is auto generate
the problem is, i want to get `nomor nasabah` value from different form, through the datagridview. take a look at the following picture

[image]

there's a button `ambil` to retrieve the `nomor nasabah` value, and pass them to `nomor nasabah` textbox.text

i have successfully to get the `nomor_nasabah` value from datagridview. it is shown like the following picture
[image]

how do i pass the value to the `tambah tabungan` . `nomor nasabah` textbox.text ?
i have set the textbox modifier into `public` so when i click the `ambil` button, the textbox is filled with the retrieved value automatically.

how do i do that ?

i did the following code, and idk why it doesn't work

here is the `ambil` button code

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Tabungan.Tambah tambahtabungan = new Tabungan.Tambah();
        //nomornya is the retrieved value            
        tambahtabungan.textBox2.Text = nomornya;
    }
```

here is the `cari` button code, to show `getCustomer` form

```
 private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (getcustomer == null || getcustomer.IsDisposed)
        {
            getcustomer = new getNasabah();                
            getcustomer.Show();
        }
    }
```

Comment: How are the forms created, and when are they shown? Is the getCustomer form shown first? Are they in the same project? If you open the getCustomer form from the Tabungan.Tambah form, then when you create the getCustomer form, you can pass the instance of the Tabungan.Tambah form to a variable, and when you click ambil, use that reference to get the textbox.

Comment: How are you populating your DataGridView initially?  Normally I've seen it make more sense to modify the object that the Grid is databound to, and then simply refresh the grid.

Comment: Which button is `Button2`?

Comment: @RomanoZumbé that is the `ambil` button

@seekerOfKnowledge no, we have to show the `tambah tabungan` form first, then when i click `cari` on `tambah tabungan` form. it display `get customer` form to retrieve the `nomor nasabah` value

Comment: please provide us the code where you open the `getCustomer` form and the code where you retrieve the `nomor nasabah` value.

Comment: done, please take a look of my thread, i have updated the thread

Comment: Check this answer out. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1665533/communicate-between-two-windows-forms-in-c-sharp

Comment: @Jmoreland91 perfect example of how to do it, as explained in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try this.

first make a public property on getCustomer form like

```
public string nomornyaValue { get; set;}
```

and modify your `ambil` button click event like, and set this property to your datagrid value.

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   nomornyaValue = nomornya;
   this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
}
```

and on `tambah tabungan` button `Cari` click call `getCustomer` form like

```
 private void Cari_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     /*getCustomer getCustomerForm = new getCustomer();
     if(getCustomerForm.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
     {
          textBox2.Text = getCustomerForm.nomornyaValue;
     }*/
    if (getcustomer == null || getcustomer.IsDisposed)
    {
        getcustomer = new getNasabah();                
    }
    if(getcustomer.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        textBox2.Text = getcustomer.nomornyaValue;
    }
 }
```

Comment: Ah yes, ShowDialog. Not a bad idea at all. +1

Comment: `simpan` button is supposed to do insert query into the database. but lemme try this one first

Comment: thanks ! it works, and i need to understand your code though. what is this line " this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;" work for ? since there's no YesNo messagebox shown ?

Comment: In the Cari_Click method, the line if(getcustomer.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) shows the getCustomer form, and it waits for a DialogResult. In the button2_Click(ambil), "this" references the current getCustomer form that is opened in Cari_Click, and he's setting the DialogResult to OK so that in the Cari_Click method, it can get the nomornyaValue to the text box.

Comment: the very once we launch the `tambah tabungan` form. what is the default, firstly value of dialog result ? . if i am not mistaken, the `dialog result` value become "OK" once we click the `ambil` button. so, don't we have to press the `Cari_click` again to execute this line ? ` if(getcustomer.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        textBox2.Text = getcustomer.nomornyaValue;
    }`

Comment: No, take a look at this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7ykbedk.aspx. "You can use this method to display a modal dialog box in your application. When this method is called, the code following it is not executed until after the dialog box is closed." So, when the Cari_Click happened, is opens the modal dialog with getCustomer, and doesn't do anything else in tambah tabungan until getCustomer is closed. You set DialogResult to OK, and close getCustomer, so tambah tabungan resumes, and checks to see if the result is OK, and if it is, sets the text in the textbox.