# Passing a textbox value from one form to another in windows application

Tags: c#

in windows application I have 2 forms: form1 containing a TextBox. I just want to use the value of the form1's textbox in form2, so in form2 I just create a object of form1 and try to access the value of textbox by writing the code:

```
form1 f1=new form1();
string value=f1.textbox1.text
```

...but the value is not coming.....please help me

Comment: Where do you create Form2? If you create it in Form1, you can provide the TextBox value as a constructor parameter.

Comment: When you create your `form1` object, the value of the `textbox1.text` property is `""`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1665688/2060966

Comment: Have you done ***ANY*** research on this before asking???

Answer (score 0):

Creating a new instance of `Form1` will not work as it a new instance, not the one you were using.  As the comments above suggest, the best option would be to create a custom constructor for `Form2` and accept the textbox value there.

```
public Form2(string form1TextBoxValue)
{
    this.ValueFromForm1 = form1TextBoxValue;
}
```

Therefore in `Form1` you can use the value in `Form2` when you instantiate it:

```
Form2 form2 = new Form2(this.textBox.Text);
```

Alternatively, you could pass the `Form1` instance to `Form2`.  This way you can access all the `Form1` values if needed.  This does mean that `Form2` has a direct dependence on `Form1` which should be avoided.

```
// In Form2
public Form2(Form form1Instance)
{
    this.Form1Instance = (Form1)form1Instance;
}

// In Form1
Form2 form2 = new Form2(this);
```