# Passing variable from form1 to form2

Tags: c#, forms, variables

I'm trying to pass a variable that is selected in a listbox that gets its content based on the contents of a directory to another form so that it can use that data.

My problem is i cant seem to figure out why this isn't working.
I'm fairly new to C#.

```
        private void buttonloadmod_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ModList.SelectedIndex = -1;
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(ModList.Text))
        {
            for (int index = 0; index < ModList.Items.Count; index++)
            {
                string item = ModList.Items[index].ToString();
                if (ModList.Text == item)
                {
                    ModList.SelectedItem = index;
                    storedvar.passedMod = item;
                    Application.Run(new Form2());
                    this.Hide();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

classfile

```
    class storedvar
{
    public static string strUsername = string.Empty;
    public static string passedMod = string.Empty;
}
```

Edit: I'm trying to get the variable from the if statement into form2.
Mostly this section seems to be whats causing my issue as nothing is passed when i try and use it. Its completely ignored even when i add in debugging code.

```
                if (ModList.Text == item)
                {
                    ModList.SelectedItem = index;
                    storedvar.passedMod = item;
                    Application.Run(new Form2());
                    this.Hide();
                    break;
                }
```

Comment: *How* isn't it working? That can mean anything.

Comment: please explain what `Is not working` what line of code is not working where you are expecting the form to show etc..also show `Form2` code constructor, class, etc.... inside of a loop you are doing `Application.Run(new Form2());` where are you showing the form of showing modal form2.. `Application.Run(new Form2());` this should be creating a new Instance no calling application run btw

Comment: Create a constructor on `Form2()` which takes your value, or add a property to the form etc..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Communicate between two windows forms](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1665533/).

Comment: @GrantWinney I'm massively new to c#. my only programming knowledge is from html/css. working with what i got. Thank you, ill try and figure out a better way of storing variables. when i looked it up for switching forms all i could find was Application.Run(new Form2()); even more so here on stack. So I'll have to try what you suggested here.

Comment: @GrantWinney Thanks a lot! I'll start reading those now.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to delete this line of code:

ModList.SelectedIndex = -1;

which is the first line in buttonloadmod_Click because the list position will never change its value.Second use show dialog by using object from form2 like

Form2 f2 = new Form2();
f2.ShowDialog();

and all code will be:

```
    private void buttonloadmod_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 f2 = new Form2();
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(ModList.Text))
        {
            for (int index = 0; index < ModList.Items.Count; index++)
            {
                string item = ModList.Items[index].ToString();
                if (ModList.Text == item)
                {
                    ModList.SelectedItem = index;
                    storedvar.passedMod = item;
                    this.Hide();
                    f2.ShowDialog();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```