# Access Form1 control from Form2

Tags: c#, forms, arguments, controls

In my application I have two forms (see image below). Clicking on "Add" button shows the second "Add wireless network" form.

[image]

After filling the form and clicking on "OK", second form adds the new profile and updates the wifi network profiles in the first form. There is a `RefreshProfiles` function in the first form and I call it in the second form with this:

```
((MainForm)this.Owner).RefreshWiFiProfiles();
```

and the "Add" button's code is this:

```
private void AddButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    NewNetworkForm newNetworkForm = new NewNetworkForm();
    newNetworkForm.Owner = this;
    newNetworkForm.ShowDialog();
}
```

This setup is working fine, but since the number of lines increased as I added new things, I wanted to divide the code. So I created a class to contain some functions.

```
namespace WirelessNetworkManager
{
    public class Tools
    {
        public static void RefreshWiFiProfiles(ListView ListViewControl)
        {
            // clear old list
            ListViewControl.Items.Clear();

            // update it
        }
    }
}
```

I call the method in the first form with this:

```
Tools.RefreshWiFiProfiles(ProfilesListView);
```

and it's working fine. The problem is, since I need to update the profiles list from the second form too, I need to call this in `NewNetworkForm`. I can access and pass the `ProfilesListView` in `MainForm` because it's in there. How can I pass a control that is in `MainForm` to a method in `NewNetworkForm` and modify it? Or is there a better approach to do this?

File structure

- MainForm.cs (WirelessNetworkManager.MainForm)
- NewNetworkForm.cs (WirelessNetworkManager.NewNetworkForm)
- Tools.cs (WirelessNetworkManager.Tools)

Comment: The better approach would be to have a ManagerTools that deals with neutral data and not with controls. The short solution is to move this logic to after the ShowDialog() call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried implementing [this. __curious_geek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/89556/this-curious-geek)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1665688/2202732) and it worked fine.

**MainForm.cs**

```
namespace WirelessNetworkManager
{
    public partial class MainForm : Form
    {
        public MainForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void AddButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // passing "this" (MainForm) to the second form
            NewNetworkForm newNetworkForm = new NewNetworkForm(this);
            newNetworkForm.ShowDialog();
        }
    }
}
```

**NewNetworkForm.cs**

```
namespace WirelessNetworkManager
{
    public partial class NewNetworkForm : Form
    {
        public NewNetworkForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        // a local variable to reference the first form (MainForm)
        private MainForm mainForm = null;

        // a second overloaded constructor accepting a form
        public NewNetworkForm(Form callingForm)
        {
            // mainForm now refers to the first form (MainForm)
            mainForm = callingForm as MainForm;
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void OKButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // create wifi profile with user input

            // accessing the ListView using this.mainForm
            Tools.RefreshWiFiProfiles(this.mainForm.ProfilesListView);

            this.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

**Tools.cs**

```
namespace WirelessNetworkManager
{
    public class Tools
    {
        public static void RefreshWiFiProfiles(ListView ListViewControl)
        {
            ListViewControl.Items.Clear();

            // iterate through wifi profiles and populate ListViewControl
        }
    }
}
```

Also the control element's (ListViewControl) Modifiers should be set to Public or Internal. Otherwise you'll get an error.

```
'WirelessNetworkManager.MainForm.ProfilesListView' is inaccessible due to its protection level
```

Answer (score 2):

You can set the **Modifiers** property of your ProfilesListView in Form2 to **Public** or **Internal** (**It's Private by default**) then you can access ProfilesListView of Form2 like this : Form2.ProfilesListView

For example:

```
ProfilesList.Refresh(Form2.ProfilesListView);
```

Your mistake is : You are creating a **new Form** when you are using RefreshWiFiProfiles() method.

You should access to existing Form2, for example if Form2 is Owner of Form1, this code works :

```
Form ownerForm = (Form)this.Owner;
Tools.RefreshWiFiProfiles(ownerForm.ProfilesListView);
```

Here is the complete example:

**Form1 declaration:**

1. Add a **ListView** to **Form1**, Set it's **Modifiers** to **Public** and add some items in it.
2. Add a **Button** to show Form2
3. Add a **Button** to clear Form2 ListView

**Form1 Code:**

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Form2 form2;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnShowForm2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            form2 = new Form2();
            form2.Owner = this;
            form2.Show();
        }

        private void btnClearForm2List_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Tools.RefreshWiFiProfiles(form2.lstViewOfForm2);
        }
    }
```

**Form2 declaration:**

1. Add a **ListView** to **Form2**, Set it's **Modifiers** to **Public** and add some items in it.
2. Add a **Button** to clear Form1 ListView

**Form2 Code:**

```
public partial class Form2 : Form

    {
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnClearForm1List_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form1 form1 = (Form1)this.Owner;
            Tools.RefreshWiFiProfiles(form1.lstViewOfForm1);
        }
    }
```

**Declaration of Tools Class:**

```
public static class Tools
{
    public static void RefreshWiFiProfiles(ListView listView)
    {
        listView.Clear();
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think I follow you. `ProfilesListView` is in the first form and I'll update it from the second form. And how do I make the second form owner of the first form? Can you give me a full example instead of one or two line of code? Something like this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L22L4bqf/2/). Just fill the blocks. Since I'm a beginner, I'm having hard time figuring it out. I've also updated the question. It should be more clear now.

Comment: I don't know if your code is working, because clearly you misunderstood my problem. There is no ListView in the second form... I found a solution now. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I know, I just made a complete sample to make you clear that you can access from **parent form** to **child form** and **the other way**. If you run my example you will understand,