# Windows Form Application how return value form one form to other

Tags: c#, windows, forms, inheritance

I'm writing an application which will be storing  film that i watched and I going to watch in future in XML file ( simple app only for training )

The main object which i use to store data in my app look like :

```
    public class FilmDto : IFilmDto
{
    public int FilmId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime? WatchedDate { get; set; }
    public int ParentId { get; set; }
    public string ParentName { get; set; }
    public FilmStatus FilmStatus { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public string SubCategory { get; set; }
}
```

All the operation is perform in Service class. There are list of film as main data file.
The service class look this :

```
public class FilmService
{
    private List<FilmDto> _films = new List<FilmDto>();
    private FilmDao _filmDao = new FilmDao();
    private FilmService()
    {
        _films = _filmDao.Load();
    }

    public static FilmService Inicialize()
    {
        return new FilmService();
    }

    public void Save()
    {
        _filmDao.Save(_films);
    }

    public List<FilmDto> GetFilmsByCriteria(FilmCriteriaDto criteria, bool withStatus)
    {
        if (withStatus)
        {
            return _films.Where(x => x.Category.Contains(criteria.Category)
                                && x.SubCategory.Contains(criteria.SubCategory)
                                && x.ParentName.Contains(criteria.ParentName)
                                && x.Name.Contains(criteria.Name)
                                && x.FilmStatus.Equals(criteria.FilmStatus)).ToList();
        }
        else
        {
            return _films.Where(x => x.Category.Contains(criteria.Category)
                                && x.SubCategory.Contains(criteria.SubCategory)
                                && x.ParentName.Contains(criteria.ParentName)
                                && x.Name.Contains(criteria.Name)).ToList();
        }
    }

    public StatisticDto GetFilmStatistic()
    {
        return new StatisticDto
        {
            TotalCount = _films.Count,
            TotalToWatch = _films.Where(x => x.FilmStatus == FilmStatus.DoObejzenia).Count(),
            TotalWatched = _films.Where(x => x.FilmStatus == FilmStatus.Obejzany).Count()
        };
    }

    public List<string> GetAllParentName()
    {
        return _films.Select(x => x.ParentName).ToList();
    }

    public void Add(FilmDto film)
    {
        _films.add(film);
    }
    // Private Methods
    private int GetNexID()
    {
        return _films.OrderByDescending(x => x.FilmId).FirstOrDefault().FilmId + 1;
    }
}
```

Now its time to form which i use to resent data. The form use service instance and call method form service to get those data ( form have only display data and do not have any logic to transform it )

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private FilmService _filmService
    public Form1()
    {
        _filmService = FilmService.Inicialize();
        InitializeComponent();
        dataGridView1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;
        FillTable(new FilmCriteriaDto(), false);
    }


    private void FillTable(FilmCriteriaDto criteria,bool witchStatus)
    {
        List<FilmDto> films = _filmService.GetFilmsByCriteria(criteria,witchStatus);
        foreach (FilmDto film in films)
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(film.Name,film.WatchedDate,film.ParentName,film.Category,film.SubCategory,film.FilmStatus);
        }
    }

    private void statisticToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        StatisticDto stats = _filmService.GetFilmStatistic();
        MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Total :{0}\nWatched {1}\nTo watch {2}"
                                        , stats.TotalCount, stats.TotalWatched, stats.TotalToWatch), "Stats INFO",MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    }

    private void addToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ...Call new form to add new film
    }
}
```

To this moment everything is quite nice. But now i need to create new form ( Form2) which will have TexBox to insert new film data to my list in service. No i don't know ho to do this.

First i thought that i change `private FilmService _filmService` to `public FilmService FilmService {get;set;}`

And in form2 create constructor where I give Form1 object like `public Form2(Form1 form)` and make call it form Form1 like : `Form2 form = new Form2(this)` . In that case i have access to that service method but it will look like `form.FilmService.Add` which is not nice. In other way i can pass FilmService object as parameter but in that way Form1 will don't know change which Form2 make. I want to create method in Form2 which will be returning `FilmDto` object to `Form1` when e.g i click buton in `Form2` is there any way to do that ?

Comment: Does singleton suit you? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx

Comment: Do you mean One instance `FilmService` but visible and accessable in every part of code ? Hmm that might work but in that case access to it will have every class and this might be not safety, i know it's only training app but i wont to make it good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use different ways to do this.

The simplest is to use [Dialogs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2chz8edb(v=vs.110).aspx). You can open your `Form2` as fialog by call [ShowDialog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7ykbedk(v=vs.110).aspx) and then just read the property if result is OK. It's a general way to implement your behavior in WinForms.

```
private void addToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Show testDialog as a modal dialog and determine if DialogResult = OK.
    if (form2.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        // Read the contents of testDialog's TextBox.
        this.txtResult.Text = form2.TextBox1.Text;
    }
}
```

Note that you must set `DialogResult` property in `Form2` to `DialogResult.OK` if user click the button and `DialogResult.Cancel` in other way. It helps you to handle scenario when user has decided not to add new movie.

The other way is to use [events](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/awbftdfh.aspx). Declare new event in `Form2` and subscribe `Form1` to this event. Raise new event on button click and pass your data as a parameter of your event.

Comment: I think that event will be better in case scen form2 will have to call another form (form3)

Answer (score 0):

First of all you can make `FilmService` static or singleton.

Also you can find some examplex for your particular task here - [Communicate between two windows forms in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1665533/communicate-between-two-windows-forms-in-c-sharp)

In my Point of View, you should use MVP pattern - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93presenter
But probably it is overkill.