# C# SQL result as variable

Tags: c#, sql, variables, datareader

On my main form I have queried the user id on submission. Once I save the id to a variable how can I call it on another windows form in the same application?

This is what I have so far

```
    private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.database.windows.net;Initial Catalog=userlogins;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=****;Password=****");
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("Select ID from users where username='" + txtUsername.Text + "' and password='" + txtPassword.Text + "' ", con);
        SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
        con.Open();

        // save SQL ID to variable
        cmd.CommandText = "Select Id from users where username = '" + txtUsername.Text + "'";
        int sqlid = ((int)cmd.ExecuteScalar());
```

Any information would be appreciated, I really need the ID on multiple other pages!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Communicate between two windows forms in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1665533/communicate-between-two-windows-forms-in-c-sharp)

Comment: What if someone's username is `'; drop table users--`?

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the [`ExecuteScalar()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar(v=vs.110).aspx) method, it's important to remember that this will only return the contents of the first cell in your results, so it can generally help to use in conjunction with a `TOP 1` statement.

Additionally, you should consider refactoring your code to use parameterization, which should help avoid nastiness like SQL Injection and will also help mitigate any syntax issues :

```
// Build your connection
using(var con = new SqlConnection("your-connection-string"))
{
     // Build your query
     var query = "SELECT TOP 1 ID FROM users WHERE username = @username AND password = @password";
     // Build a command to execute your query
     using(var cmd = new SqlCommand(con,query))
     {
          // Open your connection
          con.Open();
          // Add your parameters
          cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", txtUsername.Text);
          cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", txtPassword.Text);

          // Get your ID
          var sqlid = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
          // Do something here
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is with events:

```
public class IdChangedEventArgs : EventArgs
{
  int ChangedId {get;set;};
}

public delegate void IdChangedEventHandler(object sender, IdChangedEventArgs e);
public event IdChangedEventHandler IdChangedEvent;
private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  int sqlid = ((int)cmd.ExecuteScalar());
  IdChangedEvent(this, new IdChangedEventArgs {ChangedId = sqlid;} );
}
```

In each of your interested forms, subscribe to the events. When handled, update your GUI however you want.