# How to pass data from one form to another form textbox in windows application?

Tags: c#, class, interface, controls, windows

I'm trying to pass a variable from one form to another form textbox. The 'variable' is a result of a calculation based on the user inputs.

Below is the code for the parent form(RuleInsertForm) where I'm calling the subform(Helpformula) to get the user inputs.

```
 public partial class RuleInsertForm : Form
    { 
    public string helpformulainputs;
    }

 private void RuleInsertForm_Load(object sender,EventArgs e)
    {

  if (helpformulainputs=="")
        {
            textBox_Inputs.Text = "";
        }

        else
        {
        textBox_Inputs.Text = helpformulainputs;
        }

      }
```

Below is the code for the subform(Helpformula) where i'm passing the result variable(formulainputs) to the parent form(RuleInsertForm).

```
 public partial class HelpFormula : Form
{
    public string formulainputs = string.Empty;

   private void button_generateformula_Click(objectsender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (RuleInsertForm insertform = new RuleInsertForm())
        {

                insertform.helpformulainputs = formulainputs;
                this.Close();
                insertform.Show();

        }
     }

  }
```

Problem:
The values are getting passed to the text box but in the UI its not getting dispalyed.

so far I tried to push data back to parent form and then tried to display the data in the textbox where I failed.(I dont know where it went wrong suggest me if I can resolve the below one)

Now I need an alternative method to this for eg: instead of pushing the data back to parent form i need to make the variable available for all the forms trying to use the subform(formulainputs)

How can I acheive this process ? any suggestions are much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be that `insertForm.Show()` does not block the execution of your button handler. `Show` opens the `insertform` as non-modal.

So after `insertform` is opened, the execution is continued in `button_generateformula_Click` and when you exit the `using` block, the `insertform` is disposed and therefore closed.

To solve this you may call `insertForm.ShowDialog()` instead.

---

For different ways of communicating between Forms look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1665533/communicate-between-two-windows-forms-in-c-sharp) or simply type `communicate between forms` into the SO search box.

Comment: awesome man... thanks a lot... it got worked.. you saved my time :) I will mark this as an answer :)_

Comment: just a qucik question... this one resolved my issue.. but now im having two insertform in the UI display .... I can use an alternate method to handle this but is ther any suggestion from your end ?

Comment: please refer to the link or search term I added to my answer. there are a lot of threads about that on stackoverflow already.