# send datagridview value to another form

Tags: c#, forms, winforms, datagridview

I have 2 forms where form 1 contains textboxes and form 2 contains `DataGridView`.  So when I click search in form 1 it will open form 2 and selecting one `DataGridView` row it fills the textboxes in form 1.  I accomplished this scenario like as clicking search button in form1 I hide the form 1, and when I click `DataGridView` row in form 2 it will show me the form 1 with filled textboxes.

So here is my issue: how to achieve, without hiding the form 1, that data will be submitted from form 2.

Here is the code:

```
private void dataGridView1_RowHeaderMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            DataGridViewRow dr = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0];
            this.Hide();
            frmEmployeeDetails frm = new frmEmployeeDetails();
            frm.Show();
            frm.txtStaffID.Text = dr.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
            frm.txtStaffName.Text = dr.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
            frm.txtDepartment.Text = dr.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
            frm.cmbGender.Text = dr.Cells[3].Value.ToString();
            frm.DOB.Text = dr.Cells[4].Value.ToString();
            frm.txtFatherName.Text = dr.Cells[5].Value.ToString();
            frm.txtPAddress.Text = dr.Cells[6].Value.ToString();
            frm.txtTAddress.Text = dr.Cells[7].Value.ToString();
            frm.txtPhoneNo.Text = dr.Cells[8].Value.ToString();
            frm.txtMobileNo.Text = dr.Cells[9].Value.ToString();
            frm.dtpDateOfJoining.Text = dr.Cells[10].Value.ToString();
            byte[] data = (byte[])dr.Cells[11].Value;
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(data);
            frm.pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(ms);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }`
```

Comment: This just an observation / suggestion, but is there any reason why you're using Windows forms? Why not utilize WPF or UWP? That way you have the power of XAML and the binding framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line `frmEmployeeDetails frm = new frmEmployeeDetails();` creates a new form each time it is executed. In addition to your previously hidden form.

instead you should use a reference to your original form. here is a [link to an SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1665688/5867869) that shows you how you can do this.