# How to call a Method from one class to another

Tags: c#

I need to call some methods from one class to another class in c#. Its different from the other answers that are put up as i cant seem to find the specific answer i am looking for.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace IT2127P2_150538B
{
public partial class InputForm : Form
{
    const double cupCakePrice = 1.50;
    int noOfCupcakes, loyaltyPoints;
    double TotalPrice;
    int[] price = new int[15];
    public InputForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form Summaryform = new SummaryForm();
        Summaryform.ShowDialog();

        noOfCupcakes = int.Parse(txtNoOfCupcakes.Text);
        TotalPrice = noOfCupcakes * cupCakePrice;
        if (txtMemId.Text != "")
        {
            if ( noOfCupcakes / 2 > 0)
            {
                loyaltyPoints = (((noOfCupcakes - 1) / 2) * 3) + 1;

            }
            else
            {
                loyaltyPoints = (noOfCupcakes / 2) * 3;
            }
        }
        else
            {
            loyaltyPoints = 0;
            }
        } 
    }
}
}
```

The code above is the main class where the computation is done. Now i have to display number of cupcakes, loyalty points and total cupcake price in the code below. My problem is that i cant seem to find a way to call the variables in the primary class to the secondary class.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace IT2127P2_150538B
{
public partial class SummaryForm : Form
{
    const double cupcakePrice = 1.50;
    public SummaryForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void SummaryForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }




}
}
```

Comment: _"Now i have to display number of cupcakes, loyalty points and total cupcake price in the code below"_ -- okay, and so? Do you have a question? What, _specifically_ are you having trouble with? Your question is almost certainly a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1665533/communicate-between-two-windows-forms-in-c-sharp, but it'd be good if you'd at least explain what you're actually asking. This question is far from clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you are calling the "SummaryForm" through "InputForm", then simply overload the constructor of second class i.e. SummaryForm and pass the information through it. i.e.

```
public SummaryForm(double dblCupcakes, int intLoyaltyPoints, int intTotalCupcakePrice)
{
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

And then use this constructor when creating the object in InputForm class.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You have two options, either pass the values through the `SummaryForm` construtor.

```
public SummaryForm(int cupcakes, int loyaltypoints, double totalprice)
```

Or make sure your variables are public static. Then you can get their values.

```
// InputForm class.
public static int noOfCupcakes, loyaltyPoints;
public static double TotalPrice;

// SummaryForm class.
InputForm.noOfCupcakes;
InputForm.loyaltyPoints;
InputForm.TotalPrice;
```

Comment: Glad I could help @MohanRam.

Comment: I have encountered a problem while using the second code. Its says 'is a "field" but is used like a "type"

Comment: Did you call it using a type or an instance?

Comment: i pasted your code after the partial class.'

Comment: Put it after the SummaryForm Constructor.

Comment: Tried it. It doesnt work unfortunately

Comment: Okay, then paste your code, please.

Comment: ` {   

    public partial class SummaryForm : Form{
            InputForm.noOfCupcakes;
            InputForm.loyaltyPoints;
            InputForm.TotalPrice;

        public SummaryForm()
        {

            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void SummaryForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        } `

Comment: Here you go: `public partial class SummaryForm : Form
{
 public SummaryForm()
 {
  InitializeComponent();
  
  int SummaryFormnoOfCupcakes  = InputForm.noOfCupcakes;
  int SummaryFormloyaltyPoints = InputForm.loyaltyPoints;
  double SummaryFormTotalPrice = InputForm.TotalPrice;
 }
 
 private void SummaryForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
  
 }
 
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
  this.Close();
 }
}`