# c# communication between splashscreen and mainform into different thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, splash-screen

I've found that example ([Communicate between two windows forms in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1665533/communicate-between-two-windows-forms-in-c-sharp)) that works fine but not when the two forms are in different thread.

I've got an "System.NullReferenceException" at line 20 in MainForm (this.splashy.LabelText = i;)

The point of this script is to modified the width of the progressBar in the splashscreen when MainForm is doing his job.

Thanks in advance!

Here are the two c# classes and program file:

```
//Program.cs
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;
namespace GIS
{
    static class Program
    {
        public static SplashScreen splashy = null;
        /// <summary>
        /// Point d'entrée principal de l'application.
       /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Thread splashThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(
            delegate
            {
                //SplashScreen splashy = new SplashScreen();
                splashy = new SplashScreen();
                Application.Run(splashy);
            }
            ));
            splashThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
            splashThread.Start();
            //run form - time taking operation
            MainForm mainForm = new MainForm(splashy);
            mainForm.Load += new EventHandler(mainForm_Load);
            Application.Run(mainForm);
        }
        static void mainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //close splash
            if (splashy == null)
            {
                return;
            }
            splashy.Invoke(new Action(splashy.Close));
            splashy.Dispose();
            splashy = null;
        }
    }
}

//SplashScreen.cs
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
namespace GIS
{
    public partial class SplashScreen : Form
    {
        public SplashScreen()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        public int LabelText
        {
            get 
            { 
                return rectangleShape1.Width; 
            }
            set 
            { 
                rectangleShape1.Width = value; 
            }
       }
    }
}

//MainForm.cs
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;
namespace GIS
{
    public partial class MainForm : Form
    {
        private SplashScreen splashy = null;
        public MainForm(Form callingForm)
        {
            splashy = callingForm as SplashScreen;
            InitializeComponent();
            doWork();
        }
        private void doWork()
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
            this.splashy.LabelText = i;
            Thread.Sleep(10);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to invoke the `SplashScreen` to change it's value from an other thread like

```
this.splashy.Invoke((MethodInvoker) delegate { this.splashy.LabelText = "Requested" + repeats + "Times"; });
```

Note that the constructor

```
splashy = callingForm as SplashScreen;
```

allows `splashy` to be null - this causes your current `NullReferenceException`.

This problem is locaed in this snipped:

```
        Thread splashThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(
        delegate
        {
            splashy = new SplashScreen();
            Application.Run(splashy);
        }
        ));
        splashThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        splashThread.Start();
        //run form - time taking operation
        MainForm mainForm = new MainForm(splashy);
```

The new thread you are start is not fast enought to create the instance of `SplashScreen` before you pass it. The result - you are passing `null`.

Fix it by create the splashy before your thread starts:

```
        splashy = new SplashScreen();
        Thread splashThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(
        delegate
        {
            Application.Run(splashy);
        }
```

Comment: I still don't undersand how Invoke() works and it said impossible to convert lambda expression into Delegated type...

Comment: Sorry - a litte mistakte by me - check out the edited answer!

Comment: I've write this:
this.splashy.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate {
                    this.splashy.LabelText = i;
                });
but still the same error

Comment: `i` is not a string!

Comment: the use `i.ToString()` to set the text

Comment: Oh and LabelText is an int btw... It wasn't very clever of me to call it like that... I have no error in the script but when I start the application, I still have NullReferenceException

Comment: Like described already in my answer: Because of your constructor, splashy could be null ... check and debug what value you are passing to  `public MainForm(Form callingForm)`

Comment: Ah yes indeed... 
MainForm mainForm = new MainForm(splashy);

Comment: A possible approach is to use the null operator like `this.splashy?.LabelText = i;` to prevent the exception if splashy is null.

Comment: Well... it seems that the NullReferenceException come from the Program.cs but I have no clue why...

Comment: Hi again. despite my researchs I haven't yet resolved the NullReferenceException.  I think it comes from here 'MainForm mainForm = new MainForm(splashy);' in the Program.cs
but I don't know how to resolve the problem yet... Thx for all yours previous answers

Comment: Posted the problem in my answer

Comment: The fix is posted.