# change textbox's Text in another class without pass form as variable?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have Form1 with Textbox. Form1 call class1, class1 call class2. So how to set Textbox from class2 without passing Form1 as variable.

Comment: Show your code you tried to do it?

Comment: Only `Form1` should have access to the textbox. There are a variety of decoupled ways to accomplish this. Depending on the exact scenario, it's likely one of the best ways is for `class2` to expose an event that is raised at the time new text is available to be set. Then `Form1` can subscribe to the event and retrieve the text itself. You may need to reflect this event in `class1` as well; again, depends on the exact scenario (you've provided practically no context). See [my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29872737) for an example of how the event-based approach would work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your question is so unsightly but here `delegate` is one of the approach to achieve your scenario here is an example please refer it.

```
// FORM1
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Class1 cls1 = new Class1();
        cls1.textChange += Cls1_textChange; ;
        cls1.YourFunctionInClass1();
    }

    private void Cls1_textChange(string str)
    {
        textBox1.Text = str;
    }
}

// CLASS1
public class Class1
{
  internal delegate void TextChangeDelegate(string str);
  internal event TextChangeDelegate textChange;

  public void YourFunctionInClass1()
  {
     Class2 cls2 = new Class2();
     cls2.textChange += Cls2_textChange;
     cls2.YourFunctionInClass2();
  }

  private void Cls2_textChange(string str)
  {
     textChange(str);
  }
}

// CLASS2
public class Class2
{
  internal delegate void TextChangeDelegate(string str);
  internal event TextChangeDelegate textChange;

  public void YourFunctionInClass2()
  {
     textChange("Hello I am from Class2");
  }
}
```

Comment: many thanks you, That's what I'm looking for