# Display textBox.Text in Windows Form with "idx" iterating through for loop

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2010

This is my first C# project. I have two .cs files, one which has all the GUI related stuff (Form1.cs) and one which has my processing (GMF.cs). When "Start" (a `Button`) on GUI is clicked by user, control passes to Form1.cs, which internally calls GMFMat() present in GMF.cs file.

In Form1.cs, I have:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) // Start Processing button clicked.
{
    GMF n = new GMF();
    func_out = n.GMFMat(inputs_GUI, this.progressBar1, this.textBox_imageNumber);
}

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) // Increment Progress Bar
{
    progressBar1.Increment(1);
}

private void textBox_imageNumber_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Text = textBox_imageNumber.Text;
    Console.Write("Text = " + textBox_imageNumber.Text);
}
```

In GMF.cs, I have:

```
class GMF
{
public Tuple<string, int> GMFMat(in_params input_from_GUI, System.Windows.Forms.ProgressBar bar, System.Windows.Forms.TextBox textBox_ImgNumber) 
{
    double nth_file = 0;
    double num_files = 100
    foreach (string dir in dirs) // For our example, say 100 ierations
    {
        nth_file = nth_file + 1;
        textBox_ImgNumber.Text = nth_file.ToString();
        // Progress bar updates in each iteration, and I can see it as it progresses on the windows Form during execution. 
        bar_value_percent = nth_file / num_files * 100;
        bar.Value = int.Parse(Math.Truncate(bar_value_percent).ToString());
    }
}
}
```

Form1.cs[Design] has a TextBox (which I simlpy dragged and dropped from Toolbox). I renamed (Name) = textBox_imageNumber

- The value increments by 1 every-time it enters the for loop.
- The basic purpose of doing this is because I want the user to know (Display a message on Form Application) everytime the for loop finishes 1000 iterations.

When I run the code above, I notice the following:

1. On the Console window, the output is as expected: `Text = 1, Text = 2, ... Text = 100` as the program proceeds. - *this shows that the value of variable in textBox_ImgNumber.Text is being updated inside the for loop of GMF.cs, and reaches Form1.cs.*
2. However, on the Form, the value in text box is blank while the program runs (inside the for loop). As soon as it comes out of `func_out = n.GMFMat(inputs_GUI, this.progressBar1, this.textBox_imageNumber);`, the textBox's value is displayed as 100.

I want the value of text box on the form to be updated as and when the for loop iterates (as I see on Console window).  How can I do this?

I use Visual Studio, C# on Visual Studio 2010, .NET Framework 4 Client Profile

I know my Form is working well with respect to processing, etc since other functions are communicated well between the two .cs files.

For example, I also have a progress bar whose progress I can see when the program is being executed.

Comment: `GMF n = new GMF();` This form is never displayed, so the user is never interacting with it.

Comment: Are you trying to [communicate between two forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1665533/)?

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I will probably update my question to address your points above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

I had to include the line: `Application.DoEvents();`

So in Form1.cs:

```
private void textBox_imageNumber_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     this.Text = textBox_imageNumber.Text;
     Console.Write("Text = " + textBox_imageNumber.Text);
     Application.DoEvents();
}
```