# Updating the Datagridview on Form1, when buttonclick on Form2

Tags: c#, database, winforms, datagridview

Datagridview = `DataGridMain`
Form1 = `MainPage`
Form2 = `ExpensesForm`

What I'm trying to do is simply, update the datagrid (`DataGridMain`) on `MainPage` when the Confirm button is clicked. I apologize if this has been answered before but after trying every solution that has been posted, I could not get it to work. The Datagrid updates when I close and reopen the application but it doesn't when the Confirm button on `ExpensesForm` is clicked. This is what I've got so far:

MainPage:

```
    public void LoadDatabase()
    {
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM datagrid", "server = DESKTOP-8QADBBH; database = test; UID = test; password = test");
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds, "datagrid");
        DataGridMain.DataSource = ds.Tables["datagrid"].DefaultView;
    }
    private void MainPage_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LoadDatabase();
    }
```

ExpensesForm:

```
MainPage mainPage = new MainPage();

    private void ButtonConfirmExpenses_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bool success = double.TryParse(TextBoxExpensesPrice1.Text, out double userInput);
        string mainconn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConn"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection(mainconn);
        string sqlquery = "insert into [dbo].[DATAGRID] (CATEGORY, TRANSACTIONS) values (@CATEGORY, @TRANSACTIONS)";
        SqlCommand sqlcomm = new SqlCommand(sqlquery, sqlconn);
        sqlconn.Open();

        if (success)
        {
            if (ComboBoxExpensesCategory1.SelectedItem == null)
            {
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Invalid Input. Please choose a category.");
            }
            else
            {
                sqlcomm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TRANSACTIONS", TextBoxExpensesPrice1.Text.ToString());
                sqlcomm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CATEGORY", ComboBoxExpensesCategory1.Text.ToString());
                sqlcomm.ExecuteNonQuery();
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM datagrid", "server = DESKTOP-8QADBBH; database = test; UID = test; password = test");
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                da.Fill(ds, "datagrid");
                mainPage.DataGridMain.DataSource = ds.Tables["datagrid"].DefaultView;
                sqlconn.Close();
                this.Close();
                mainPage.LoadDatabase();
                mainPage.DataGridMain.Update();
                mainPage.DataGridMain.Refresh();

            }
        }
        else
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Invalid Input. Please insert a number.");

        }
    }
```

Comment: Without more info, it appears you are “creating a NEW” `MainPage` in the `ExpensesForm` with the line… `MainPage mainPage = new MainPage();` this is creating a NEW `MainPage` form and from what I can see it is NOT “showing” this “new” form, therefore the line of code… `mainPage.DataGridMain.DataSource = ds.Tables["datagrid"].DefaultView;` is setting the data source on a form that IS NOT SHOWN. I am betting you need to either PASS the first form to the second form in its constructor, or pass the grid to the second forms constructor.

Comment: First of all, thanks alot for taking the time to answer my question. But being a complete amateur, I have no idea how to do either of those things. I don't understand what "pass" means in this context. I'd appreciate it if you took the time and wrote some code i could use (assuming that it would'nt be too much code). I just tried 'mainPage.ShowDialog()' and it looks like you are right. But the first form and the expenses form, both stay open after I click Confirm. Thanks in advance

Comment: There is a lot of info on how to do this. In addition, there are several ways to do this. I recommend you take a look at the selected answer to this question…  [Communicate between two windows forms in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1665533/communicate-between-two-windows-forms-in-c-sharp) … Pay attention to “how” the second form is called from the first form, and pay attention to the second forms constructor. If you can’t get it working, then you should show “how” the first form is calling the second form in addition you should show the second forms constructor.