# Although the Modifiers property is public, I want to get the data in form1 from form2 but it does not

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to use the data form `Form1` in `Form2`.

I did it in Public, but it didn't happen again.

I Can't get data from `Form1` into `Form2`. How can I fix this problem?

.

```
Form1 f1 = new Form1();
Random rnd = new Random();
Font fnt = new Font(f1.comboBox1.SelectedIndex.ToString(),12);
TextureBrush tbr = new TextureBrush(Image.FromFile("kaplan.jpg"),
System.Drawing.Drawing2D.WrapMode.Tile);
g.DrawString(f1.textBox1.Text, fnt, tbr, rnd.Next(0, 1024), rnd.Next(0, 768));
```

[image]

Comment: What it is the exact error?

Comment: Your question has some wierdness. The Properties accesds modifer can be public, but Modifiers do not have properties. | While you create a Form1 instance, you do not show it. Did you expect a totally different Form1 Instance to realate to the new created one?

Comment: The exact error is that I can't get the data in form1 from form2, even though it's public.

Comment: How did you show form2? Show us that code. You are supposed to pass a reference of the existing Form1 to form2 when calling `Show()` or `ShowDialog()`.

Comment: thank you. but we can pull the properties in form1 to form2 normally. but I couldn't.

Comment: Form2 frm = new Form2();
            frm.Show();
            this.Hide();

Comment: There is a lot of info on how to pass variables between forms. In addition, there are several ways to do this. I recommend you take a look at the selected answer to this question… [Communicate between two windows forms in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1665533/communicate-between-two-windows-forms-in-c-sharp) … Pay attention to “how” the second form is called from the first form, and pay attention to the second forms constructor. If you can’t get it working, then you should show “how” the first form is calling the second form in addition you should show the second forms constructor.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Communicate between two windows forms in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1665533/communicate-between-two-windows-forms-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Go to the `Form1.cs` hold `ctrl` and press on the `InitializeComponent();`

Hold `ctrl` and press on the name `comboBox1` in the line `this.comboBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox();`

Now change the lines

```
private System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox comboBox1;
private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox textBox1;
```

to

```
public System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox comboBox1;
public System.Windows.Forms.TextBox textBox1;
```

Here are some images for you to follow:

[image]

[image]

[image]