# Hide and unhide one form in winform

Tags: c#, winforms, show-hide

I have two form: Form1 and Form2. Both of it already have data.

- After I scan barcode in Form1, Fom1 will be hidden, Form2 will show and somethings.
- After Form2 finish, Form1 will show again and Form2 will be hidden.

It's cycle.

I tried with:

```
///In Form1
Frm2 Form2 = new Frm2();
Form2.show();
this.Hide();

///In Form2
Frm1 Form1 = new Frm1();
Form1.show();
this.Hide();
```

But i think it make a new form with no data.

So, how can i unhide form which was hidden?

Comment: Not yet, i still finding solution

Comment: Did you read the code you posted? You create `Form2` twice, show it twice, and then use `this` without any idea what `this` references.

Comment: @MrAngel If you want only one instance of Form2, then don't create it every time you want to show it. Create instance of Form2 somewhere in constructor of Form1 and then only show/hide when needed.

Comment: @KenWhite sr. it's my bad. It's for Frm1 form2 = new Frm1.

Comment: @DzianisKarpuk can u give example? I need only hide and unhide it

Comment: Can anyone answer me who can close this post. It's not same problem with link i receved. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1665533/communicate-between-two-windows-forms-in-c-sharp

Comment: @MrAngel no, your question is closed, it is unsuitable to post code in comment.