# How to use created Instance on all forms / How to make my instance public C# windowsforms

Tags: c#, winforms, class

Hello it is probably easy question for you, I'm a beginner and I'm making my own simple game and I want to use a Class:Gamer, which I want to initialize **in MainWindow(Form1.cs)** from a save file. From then, I want to use it **on another Forms** aswell, but somehow I can't make the instance go public.

Could you tell me what I'm doing wrong? Or is there another way how to solve this?
Thank you :)

Code on Form1:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace THE_GAME
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        public static Gamer Player;
        private void MainWindow_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //load from savefile   lvl;hp;money;gun;armor,name
            string allData = File.ReadAllText("../../saveFile/save.txt");
            string[] dataFromSave = new string[5];
            dataFromSave = allData.Split(';');

            Player = new Gamer(dataFromSave[0], dataFromSave[1], dataFromSave[2], dataFromSave[3], dataFromSave[4], dataFromSave[5]);
        }
    }
}
```

Code on secondForm2:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing.Text;

namespace THE_GAME
{
    public partial class Statistics : Form1
    {
        public Statistics()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void Statistics_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //labels stats
            labelName.Text = Form1.Player.GetName();
            labelHealth.Text = Form1.Player.GetHealth().ToString();
            labelMoney.Text = Form1.Player.GetMoney().ToString();

        }
        private void buttonBack_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MainMenu menu = new MainMenu();
            menu.Show();
            this.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Communicate between two windows forms in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1665533/communicate-between-two-windows-forms-in-c-sharp)

Comment: You should not be deriving Statistics from Form1, thats a very odd thing to do.

Comment: FWIW: it's unusual to have an event handler with a name like ` MainWindow_Load` in a Forms class named `Form1`.  That's not what the tools will auto-name the handler?  Do you have it wired up correctly?  If you put a breakpoint in it, does it get hit?

Comment: Yes, it's working fine, I have changed the name of the Form1 recently so that's why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get at the Gamers Player object from a different Form just do

```
Form1.Player;
```

ie

```
var nam =  Form1.Player.Name;
Form1.Player.Die();
```

etc

PS As I said in a comment - its extremely odd to dereive a form of yours from another one of your forms. Like this

```
 public partial class Statistics : Form1
```

Comment: Hello, but the code: public static Gamer Play; 
gives me an error:
Error CS0052 Inconsistent Availability: The Gamer field type is less available than the Form1.Player field.

Comment: And thank you for the advice in postscript, I have changed it already.

Comment: @koli did you make the Gamer class public? You didnt show it, not the field, the actual class defintion