# How to add content to DataGridView from another form?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have **Main Form** which connected with two other forms by buttons(**Content Adding Form** and **Form with DataGridView**). Form with **DataGridView** must be without button (which go over to **Content Adding Form**).

**Content Adding Form:**

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FormDataGridView main = this.Owner as FormDataGridView;
        if (main != null)
        {    
            DataRow nRow = main.databaseDataSet.Tables[0].NewRow();
            int rc = main.dataGridView1.RowCount + 1;
            nRow[0] = rc;
            nRow[1] = textBox1.Text;
            nRow[2] = textBox2.Text;
            nRow[3] = textBox3.Text;
            nRow[4] = textBox4.Text;
            main.databaseDataSet.Tables[0].Rows.
            Add(nRow);
            main.studentsTableAdapter.Update(main.databaseDataSet.students);
            main.databaseDataSet.Tables[0].AcceptChanges();
            main.dataGridView1.Refresh();
            textBox1.Text = "";
            textBox2.Text = "";
            textBox3.Text = "";
            textBox4.Text = "";
        }
    }
```

**Main Form:**

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ContentAdding add = new ContentAdding();
        add.Show();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FormDataGridView view = new FormDataGridView();
        view.Show();
    }
```

https://www.linkpicture.com/q/photo_4.png

Comment: You should be passing the data you need into the constructor and or set a property in `ContentAdding` with your data. FWIW, I would create a new class to hold your data and add this to a collection of some sorts and finally you could set this as your `DataSource` to the grid.

Comment: Note that you're trying to get the Form's Owner (`this.Owner`), but you never set the Owner in code (`add.Show();` should be `add.Show(this);`)

Comment: In the `ContentAdding` form, the first line of code in the method is… `FormDataGridView main = this.Owner as FormDataGridView;` … ? … This implies that the `ContentAdding` form was created and shown by the `FormDataGridView` … ? … where is the `FormDataGridView` code and where is it creating and showing the `ContentAdding` form?

Comment: In the current code, it looks like `MainForm` is creating and showing the `ContentAdding` form and in that case `main` will always be `null` because it is not a `FormDataGridView`… it is a `MainForm`… ? … can you clarify any of this? It appears you are making this far more complex than it has to be.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Communicate between two windows forms in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1665533/communicate-between-two-windows-forms-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0):

It should be sufficient to pass from main form to others your main.databaseDataSet.