# Visual Studio: reset user settings when debugging

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, settings, reset

In a C# Winforms-App I have several user settings stored.

Is there an easy way to clear those settings each time I start debugging the project from Visual Studio 2008?

Otherwise it always starts up with the settings from the last debug-session.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Add a pre-build action to delete:

`%USERPROFILE%\Local Settings\Application Data\[AppName]\...\[Version]\user.config`

or if your version number changes alot just delete

`%USERPROFILE%\Local Settings\Application Data\[AppName]\`

Comment: Any chance you would know how to do the same thing for VS 2010??? I just messed up my debugger view and can't figure out how to get back to default... (grrr GUIs...)

Comment: I would recommend using the system variable `%localappdata%` instead.  On my Windows 10 system for example, the folder `%USERPROFILE%\Local Settings` does not exist.

Comment: On Windows 10, it's called AppData but there is more to it than this as despite removing the folder the settings kept getting loaded.
Ended up using the answer from Smolla, which did the trick

Answer (score 63):

Had the same question and found an answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/2117359/488794

```
Properties.Settings.Default.Reset()
```

You can use this following statement to only reset if you're debugging:

```
if(Debugger.IsAttached) 
   Settings.Default.Reset();
```

tested VS2012 .Net 4.0 ([Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debugger.isattached%28v=vs.110%29.aspx))

Comment: Also you can use 
#if DEBUG  
Properties.Settings.Default.Reset()  
#endif

Comment: Wouldn't recommend a #if because it can happen that a debug build is sent to testers which might want to test if settings persist.

Comment: This did the trick for me on VS2008 NET3.5 Windows 10 ... don't ask

Answer (score 9):

Adding to the above answers, here a copy-paste solution that works for most settings:

```
rmdir /q /s %localappdata%\[company name]\[AppName]
```

Note that for most cases it's best to delete everything under %localappdata%[company name]. Check the app data stored there and choose what's best for you.

Answer (score 2):

Run->Type "appdata"

Navigate to Local->/

Delete all files related to the project

Answer (score 0):

Here are two possible ways to do it:

- use either the pre build or post build event command line, you put delete commands and such in there or run a batch file or script
- have a play with the Start Action options of the start up project, you can specify an external program with command line arguments to be run first

Answer (score 0):

Based on other answers: just search on `C:` or `C:\Users\<YourUser>` for `user.config` and delete or rename that file.